# Jest's --findRelatedTests doesn't notice JSON files

Tags: jestjs

I'm using `jest --findRelatedTests` in my pre-commit hook and it works fine. The only thing that it doesn't notice are changed JSON files.

If I have a JSON file like this

```
{
  "message": "Hello"
}
```

And I change it to something like this

```
{
  "messsssage": "Hello"
}
```

The following code would break, but it wouldn't be tested by `jest --findRelatedTests`

```
import data from './data.json'

export default () => data.message.length
```

Is there an option to configure Jest to watch out for changed JSON files also?

**Edit:** It seems to be a bug in the Jest package, you can find the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7499

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jest-json to your jest config.

```
{
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "jest-json"
}
```

Or if you're already using another test framework, create a setup file and require each of them:

```
require("jest-json");
```

For further information, you can refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-json)